# NODE JS- EXPRESS: Unable to retrieve value from HTTP Context for POST and PUT requests while it works for GET

Tags: node.js, express, httpcontext

In Node.js and Express framework, I am unable to retrieve value from HTTP Context for POST and PUT requests while it works for GET. I am using httpContext to set a unique requestId identifier so that I can use it while logging to trace API requests.

I found out that HttpContext could be reset by some other packages in middle ware, is there a better way to store data for a request scope which could be accessed in all modules.

app.js file

```
        const app = express();
        app.use(httpContext.middleware);
        //Assign unique identifier to each req
        app.use(function (req, res, next) {
          let test = uuidv1();
          httpContext.set("reqId", test);
          next();
        });

        const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
        Connection.setupPool();
        app.use(express.json());
        app.use(helmet());
        if (app.get("env") === "development") {
          app.use(morgan("tiny"));
        }

        //use to access a resource in the root through url
        app.use(express.static("resource"));

        app.use("/users", userRouter);
        //Code For Instagram authentication Using Passport
        logger.info("End-Instagram Authentication Configuration");
        app.listen(PORT, () => {
          logger.info(`app running port ${PORT}`);
        });
```

My code for retrieving the reqId from httpContext

logger.js

```
   message = httpContext.get("reqId") ? "RequestId: " + 
             httpContext.get("reqId")+" "+ message: ""+ message ;
```

Comment: That seems like some code is missing at the top. If that is the case please add all the relevant code. Just in case please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: At top  I  only have few import statements for modules.

Comment: How can somebody recreate your problem if you do not share *all* your code?

Comment: I have added the dependencies, but I dont think it will help anybody understand my problem better. May be I am wrong.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

i hope this solution solve your problem and save many hours for anyone that have this problem

you can just use bindEmitter to solve the problem

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    httpContext.ns.bindEmitter(req);
    httpContext.ns.bindEmitter(res);
    var requestId = req.headers["x-request-id"] || uuidv4();
    httpContext.set("requestId", requestId);
    console.log('request Id set is: ', httpContext.get('requestId'));
    next();
});
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, middleware that queues requests confuses httpContext as it no longer associates the message with the correct context. Binding to the `req`/`res` events is needed to ensure the correct context is picked up when the request is actually processed.

Comment: Exactly this just happened as you said @Duncan

Comment: Thank you so much for your good service. My brain and heart thank you.

Answer (score 15):

I am having the same issue. Attempted the bindEmitter solution above and that did not work.

After a few trail and errors REF#1 removing the `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` header from my clients POST invocation allowed values in the context to be set/retained.

This led me to suspect there was an issue with how the `body-parser(v1.19.0)` middleware and `express-http-context(v1.2.3)` interacts.

When I reversed the order of the middleware such that `body-parser` comes before `express-http-context` httpContext was working as expected (without having to do REF#1 ) E.g:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json()); //must come before
app.use(httpContext.middleware);
```

Comment: In my case, it worked after i put app.use(httpContext.middleware); after  app.use(express.json());